# How to get grouped_options_for_select to display the selected option on the field when searching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using grouped_options_for_select on my dropdown select field. However, when I select an option, it doesn't stay on the field as a selected option, (after I push the "search" button), but the field jumps to the first option on the list.

Search still works correctly, but I would like the field to show what the user was searching for.

This is what I tried:

```
  <% grouped_options = [['Europe',["London, UK", "Stockholm, Sweden"]], ['USA', ["San Francisco", "Mountain View"]]] %>
  <%= f.select :location_cont, grouped_options_for_select(grouped_options) %>
```

It works correctly if I display all the options as such:

```
<%= f.select :location_cont, ["", "San Francisco, USA", "Mountain View, USA", "Palo Alto, USA"] %>
```

In the above case the selected option, that is searched, stays 'active' on the list after pushing the "search" button. But I would like to sort the options based on countries, that's why I prefer the first option with grouped_options_for_select.

Comment: try this `grouped_options = ['Europe' => ["London, UK", "Stockholm, Sweden"], 'USA' => ["San Francisco", "Mountain View"]]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no it doesn't work for me.

Comment: `grouped_options = {
  'Europe' => ["London, UK", "Stockholm, Sweden"],
  'USA' => ["San Francisco", "Mountain View"]
}` is working for me.